# Variable is not in scope error when relay-compiling Relay Modern code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, relaymodern, react-relay

I have the following simple Relay Modern code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {
    QueryRenderer,
    graphql
} from 'react-relay'


import environment from '../../../../../environment'

const CompanyItemQuery = graphql`

query CompanyItem_Query {
  node(id: $companyId) {
    id
    ...on Company {
      id
      name
    }
 }
}
`

class CompanyItem extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
                <QueryRenderer
                    environment={environment}
                    query={CompanyItemQuery}
                    variables={{
                        companyId: 'test',
                    }}
                    render={({error, props}) => {
                        <div>
                            <p>Relay loaded {props.name} company</p>
                        </div>
                }}
                />
        );
    }
};

export default CompanyItem;
```

I'm trying to relay-compile the code before running and I'm getting the following error:

```
> relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./src/data/schema.graphql

HINT: pass --watch to keep watching for changes.
Parsed default in 0.08s

Writing default
Invariant Violation: RelayApplyFragmentArgumentTransform: variable `companyId` is not in scope.
    at invariant (D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\fbjs\lib\invariant.js:44:15)
    at transformValue (D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\relay-compiler\bin\relay-compiler:4505:28)
    at D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\relay-compiler\bin\relay-compiler:4497:18
    at Array.map (native)
    at transformArguments (D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\relay-compiler\bin\relay-compiler:4496:16)
    at transformField (D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\relay-compiler\bin\relay-compiler:4417:15)
    at D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\relay-compiler\bin\relay-compiler:4476:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at transformSelections (D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\relay-compiler\bin\relay-compiler:4461:15)
    at transformNode (D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\node_modules\relay-compiler\bin\relay-compiler:4385:21)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "relay"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mom-client@3.0.0 relay: `relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./src/data/schema.graphql`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mom-client@3.0.0 relay script 'relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./src/data/schema.graphql'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mom-client package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./src/data/schema.graphql
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mom-client
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mom-client
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\DEV\WORKSPACE\client\npm-debug.log
```

I can't find out why my variable `companyId` is not in scope, as it is defined in the `variables` section of the `QueryRenderer` as stated in the documentation.

If I use a fixed value for id (example `node id: "Company:59b2cda12504b914cc398100"`) code is relay-compiled and I can get my data fetched normally. The problem arises when I need to choose the id dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you missed declaring the variable (and type) in the query name - so this:

```
query CompanyItem_Query($companyId: ID!) {
```

instead of this:

```
query CompanyItem_Query {
```

You can see more context in the example on the relay site -
 https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/query-renderer.html

Comment: Yes, simple missing.